# Disabling HTTPS in Axis2 web service

Tags: web-services, https, apache-axis

I have created an Axis2 web service from Netbeans and deployed it successfully in Tomcat 6 on my web server.
When I use for instance SoapUI or Taverna to consume the web service, the server offers both HTTP and HTTPS methods to invoke it. However, using the HTTPS method renders a 404 error. (Probably because there is a server admin panel running on port 8443, but that doesn't matter right now.)

The problem is that my web service clients default to using the HTTPS service. I figured the simplest thing I could do to get the basic service to work, would be to disable the HTTPS endpoint, as the HTTP version runs flawlessly and I don't need the added security. But now I've spent hours on finding out how to do that, without success. The WSDL returned by Axis2 contains entries for HttpsSoap11Endpoint but the WSDL that's bundled in my .AAR file after the build does not.

Does anybody know how to make Axis2 offer just HTTP endpoints?

Comment: Try commenting out the https transport receiver in your axis2.xml

Comment: @karoberts - can you answer this question so it can be marked as "answered"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In axis2.xml, comment out the https transport receiver to disable the HTTPS endpoint.